# run bundled python script in clickonce application

Tags: c#, python, wpf, deployment, clickonce

I'm trying to run a Python script from a WPF application, but I can't figure out how to find the file on the client machine. I know ClickOnce installs the files to AppData\Local\, but that seems like a poor way to search for the script.

In my code, I'm starting a shell as follows:

```
var p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Python27\python.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("{0} {1}", ScriptName, args);
//p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"<path\to\project>";
p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.Start();
string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
p.WaitForExit();
```

On my development machine, the `WorkingDirectory` parameter makes it all work if I set it to the project path because that's where the Python script resides.

I included the script in the ClickOnce file manifest and I've verified that it ends up in each version of the application deployment. I've also verified that the file ends up on the client machine in the obfuscated hierarchy, so everything is in place except I can't get my WPF application to actually run it. I could always copy the file to a known place on the machine, but that completely defeats the point of ClickOnce.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work, but I'm not 100% sure how. Regardless, here's what I did in case it helps someone else.

Don't set the process working directory (already commented out in my question)
Set the Python script properties as follows:

1. Build Action = Content
2. Copy to Output Directory = Copy Always

In the Publish tab under Project Properties, set the script to `Include` in Application Files.

With the above changes, my application deploys correctly on client machines.